# SQL how do I select a IDs which contains at least a certain condition and occurs more than once?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to query ID data which satisfy the following conditions:

1. Must have more than 1 ID occurrence (2 rows appearing or more)
2. IDs which have Clinic B appearing at least once.

Data Table:

```
ID | Clinic
-----------
1  | A
1  | B
2  | A
2  | C
3  | B
3  | C
4  | B
```

The result should be ID 1 and 3. 
I can get 1) with the following:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) 
FROM Data Table
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(ID)>1
```

but can't incorporate condition 2) in.

Comment: In this example from your "Data Table" the 4 can not be shown because it appears only one time ? And if you put OR and not AND between conditions then you will have ID 3 in the results.

Comment: Why not `ID 3` as well? It is occurring 2 times and also have Clinic `B`

Comment: I made a typo. It should include 3 as well. thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @spidermarn then you have an answer that you can upvote and mark as correct one.

Comment: Be precise. Must satisfy BOTH conditions or EITHER condition? Does your table allow duplicates? Should duplicates be considered for your first condition? Be careful what you assume.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to count number of `B` appear per `ID`

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) 
FROM  [Data Table]
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1
AND    SUM (CASE WHEN Clinic = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  >= 1
```

Answer (score -1):

I've tried this and got similar answer to @Squirrel

```
SELECT t1.* from Data Table t1, Data Table t2
WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID AND Clinic = 'B'
```

Comment: This is not correct. With this query the first request will not be satisfied: "Must have more than 1 ID occurrence (2 rows appearing or more)" The correct answer is the one from @Squirrel and I do not believe there is a better one. Why do you try and further ?